# how to deselect a row from tableview in iphone using monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

If I click on any of the rows of a TableView, it navigates to its details page. Navigating from the details page back to the tableview page, I am getting the page that shows as selected the row which was previously selected. I need to deselect rows which were previously selected while  navigating from another screen to the tableview page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `RowSelected` override, call `DeselectRow`, i.e.

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, false);
    .....
}
```

Comment: Why false? I would use tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true) so that the it fades away nicely.

Comment: I used `false` to illustrate the code. If an effect is desired, then you are quite correct.

Comment: If i wrote deselect in row selected event when will i can select row?

Comment: Call it first thing in RowSelected. That way, no row will remain selected.

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath call this [tableview deSelectRowAtIndexPath];